# How to protect a NFC chip from being copied?

Tags: security, nfc, access-control

I want to develop an NFC access application and I'm thinking about how to prevent people from copying their tag.

I read that some NFC chips have a "password secured memory" part where data can be stored that it is protected with a password. If I understand correctly, this password is required every time the chip is read. This way I can protect the NFC tag from being copied by simply storing the user GUID into the "password secured memory". As the data can't be read, it can't be copied, right?

The only chip I found that supports this are the "MIFARE Classic" and "MIFARE DESFire" chip, where the "MIFARE DESFire" chip is too expensive for our application.

So now my questions:

- How are NFC chips usually protected from being copied in access control applications? (e.g. hotel rooms, garage doors or office buildings?)
- Are there other cards than the mentioned MIFARE cards that have a "password protected memory" ?
- How secure is the password protected memory on e.g. a MIFARE Classic card. (if there are ways to read the data after a few seconds (e.g. bruteforce) it may not secure enough for us)

There is a lot of information available on the internet about NFC chips but in my experience its kind of a wild west where everyone writes something but not everything is supported by all chips/readers and writers. I don't see the woods for the trees anymore..

Comment: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/sp-14/materials/arsenal/sp-14-Almeida-Hacking-MIFARE-Classic-Cards-Slides.pdf

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63483/how-do-nfc-tags-prevent-copying